# Connector type on Atwood Truck Camper Jack Control Board

Tags: connector

I wanted to hard wire controls to level my truck camper because the jack system only comes with a wireless remote from the factory.  But the jack system also controls the porch lights.  So I have to find the remote in the dark to turn the lights on outside.

The board has what I think is a molex connector on it.  When I momentarily ground a pin it turns on a light or operates a jack.  I want to wire switches up to the pins, but I would really like to buy the correct connector plug instead of just sticking individual jumper wires into the sockets.

I have searched for molex connectors and some look close, but I can't find the pin layout that the connector has.  Any help locating this connector would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Alta Series Jack Control Board, what is that connector in the middle?]

[image: Trying to measure the pin distance with this picture.]

Comment: Agreed that it looks like a Molex, though I've never seen a board-mount male connector in these series. Can you measure the pin pitch? Easiest would be to measure the distance between the first and 6th pin and divide by 5.

Comment: The are is tight brought the board and all I have is a tape measure, I posted a picture.  I measured .5" between pin 1 and 4 then divided by 4 to get 0.125".

Comment: Oops, divide by 3 not 4, give pitch of 0.167"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks very close to a Molex Mini Fit Jr connector. Male pins in this design are quite common.

See [mating part](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/datasheet.jsp?part=active/0039012120_CRIMP_HOUSINGS.xml)

But the strange thing is the keying in various holes. The molex doesn't have keying in different ways. Also the pins are round and the Molex one square.

You need to have a look at TE connectivity "MATE-N-LOK" series, they have similar keying as yours.

Comment: I searched for a few hours looking at different molex connectors including the Mini Fit Jr, but none of the molex connectors had the keys in the direction of the bottom left and bottom right pin.

Comment: Have a look at the TE MATE-N-LOK series connectors.

Comment: You the man! http://www.te.com/usa-en/product-1-770972-1.html, thats the board version now I can find the wire side.